# How to halt user keyboard input while a certain task is running?

Tags: c#, keyboard, console-application

I have a maze game in a console that i'm creating for programming practice. I have created an animation and will have it running after the user has read the instruction. Though unfortunately I have a found a flaw in the way I have created my animation. I use the `Console.setCursorPosition()` and `Console.Write()`. When the user hits keys on the keyboard during the animation it enters it in the middle of the animation, so it interupts it and doens't complete the animation currectly.

My question is how do I halt user input during this animation?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `Console.KeyAvailable` and `Console.ReadKey(false)`

Comment: could you give an example?

Comment: @user2195610 can you share how you are doing your animation?

Comment: I'm sorry that I havn't come back to this post in a long while but I managed to fix the problem. 

Now, the animation runs it asks which way the player would like to go and even if hitting buttons while the animation is running it places the recorded text after the question.

Comment: Note: It happened unintentionaly, but found out that if you run a Console.Read() while the timer is running throught the case then it makes the text wait there.